# Divergence of a sequence involving primes

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Let $\mathbb P$ be the set of prime numbers. I want to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p\in\mathbb P}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor\right\}=\infty,$$ using the following two facts:

- There exist positive numbers $C$ and $D$ such that $$C\leq\frac{\pi(n)\log n}{n}\leq D\quad\forall n\in\mathbb N,$$ where $\pi$ is the prime-counting function.
- $\sum_{p\in\mathbb P}1/p=\infty$.

Any hint is much appreciated.

Comment: $\lfloor x\rfloor = x - (x-\lfloor x\rfloor)$

Comment: @DanielFischer Great hint, thanks!

Comment: I honestly don't understand the downvote and the closure requests. I asked a well-defined question and I could answer it myself using a hint, which is all I asked for (as opposed to a complete solution). I asked this question in good faith purely motivated by a desire to learn—this is not a homework problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Daniel Fischer's hint and letting $\mathbb P_n\equiv\{p\in\mathbb P\,|\,p\leq n\}$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p\in\mathbb P}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor=&\,\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p\in\mathbb P_n}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor=\sum_{p\in\mathbb P_n}\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p\in\mathbb P_n}\underbrace{\left(\frac{n}{p}-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor\right)}_{<1}\\
\geq&\,\sum_{p\in\mathbb P_n}\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{p\in\mathbb P_n}1=\sum_{p\in\mathbb P_n}\frac{1}{p}-\frac{\pi(n)}{n}\geq\sum_{p\in\mathbb P_n}\frac{1}{p}-\frac{D}{\log n}\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align*}